# Using Include function in PHP, completely ignores it

Tags: php, html, web

So I currently have two files.
1. index.php
2. header.php

I want the header file to be "included" in all my other webpages, so to make it so I only have to edit that one file to make web-wide updates to the header and footers. My website does support PHP and I'm running PHP 5.4 FASTCGI. Also, all of the files were uploaded via filezilla so I know they are there. As well as the HTML working, without being put in the include function. When I do put it in it seems to just act as if nothing was "included" and goes on to generate the rest of the website, not throwing an error.

Here are my file makeups, they are both in the same directory.

1. index.php (just copied the function as everything else works, if needed I can post rest but it's large and generic right now.)

```html
<?php include'header.php';?>
```

2. header.php

```html
<?php ' 
         <!-- Header Start -->
         <header id="header">
            <!-- Header Top Bar Start -->
            <div class="top-bar">
               <div class="slidedown collapse">
                  <div class="container">
                     <div class="phone-email pull-left">
                        <a><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Call Us : +880 111-111-111</a>
                        <a href="support@fifothemes.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Email : support@fifothemes.com</a>
                     </div>
                     <div class="pull-right">
                        <ul class="social pull-left">
                           <li class="facebook"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                           <li class="twitter"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                           <li class="dribbble"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                           <li class="linkedin"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                           <li class="rss"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div id="search-form" class="pull-right">
                           <form action="#" method="get">
                              <input type="text" class="search-text-box" placeholder="Search...">
                           </form>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Header Top Bar End -->
            <!-- Main Header Start -->
            <div class="main-header">
               <div class="container">
                  <!-- TopNav Start -->
                  <div class="topnav navbar-header">
                     <a class="navbar-toggle down-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".slidedown">
                     <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa fa-current"></i>
                     </a> 
                  </div>
                  <!-- TopNav End -->
                  <!-- Logo Start -->
                  <div class="logo pull-left">
                     <h1>
                        <a href="index.html">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="pixma" width="125" height="60">
                        </a>
                     </h1>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Logo End -->
                  <!-- Mobile Menu Start -->
                  <div class="mobile navbar-header">
                     <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href=".navbar-collapse">
                     <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                     </a> 
                  </div>
                  <!-- Mobile Menu End -->
                  <!-- Menu Start -->
                  <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse menu">
                     <ul class="nav navbar-nav sf-menu">
                        <li>
                           <a id="current" href="index.html">
                           Home
                           <span class="sf-sub-indicator">
                           <i class="fa fa-angle-down "></i>
                           </span>
                           </a>
                           <ul>
                              <li><a href="index-2.html" class="sf-with-ul">Home 2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="index-3.html" class="sf-with-ul">Home 3</a></li>
                              <li><a href="index-4.html" class="sf-with-ul">Home 4</a></li>
                              <li><a href="index-nivo.html" class="sf-with-ul">Nivo Slider</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">
                           Features 
                           <span class="sf-sub-indicator">
                           <i class="fa fa-angle-down "></i>
                           </span>
                           </a>
                           <ul>
                              <li><a href="shortcodes.html" class="sf-with-ul">Shortcodes</a></li>
                              <li><a href="icons.html" class="sf-with-ul">Icons</a></li>
                              <li><a href="pricing-table.html" class="sf-with-ul">Pricing Tables</a></li>
                              <li>
                                 <a href="#" class="sf-with-ul"> 
                                 Third Level Menu 
                                 <span class="sf-sub-indicator pull-right">
                                 <i class="fa fa-angle-right "></i>
                                 </span>
                                 </a>
                                 <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">Menu Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">Menu Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">Menu Item</a></li>
                                 </ul>
                              </li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">
                           Pages
                           <span class="sf-sub-indicator">
                           <i class="fa fa-angle-down "></i>
                           </span>
                           </a>
                           <ul>
                              <li><a href="about.html" class="sf-with-ul">About Us</a></li>
                              <li><a href="services.html" class="sf-with-ul">Services</a></li>
                              <li><a href="testimonials.html" class="sf-with-ul">Testimonials</a></li>
                              <li><a href="full-width.html" class="sf-with-ul">Full Width Page</a></li>
                              <li><a href="page-left-sidebar.html" class="sf-with-ul">Left Sidebar</a></li>
                              <li><a href="page-right-sidebar.html" class="sf-with-ul">Right Sidebar</a></li>
                              <li><a href="page-left-navigation.html" class="sf-with-ul">Left Navigation</a></li>
                              <li><a href="page-right-navigation.html" class="sf-with-ul">Right Navigation</a></li>
                              
                              <li><a href="faq.html" class="sf-with-ul">FAQ</a></li>
                              <li><a href="page-404.html" class="sf-with-ul">404 Page</a></li>
         <li><a href="search-results.html" class="sf-with-ul">Search Results</a></li>
                              <li><a href="sitemap.html" class="sf-with-ul">Sitemap</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">
                           Portfolio
                           <span class="sf-sub-indicator">
                           <i class="fa fa-angle-down "></i>
                           </span>
                           </a>
                           <ul>
                              <li><a href="portfolio-two.html" class="sf-with-ul">2 Column</a></li>
                              <li><a href="portfolio-three.html" class="sf-with-ul">3 Column</a></li>
                              <li><a href="portfolio-four.html" class="sf-with-ul">4 Column</a></li>
                              <li><a href="portfolio-single.html" class="sf-with-ul">Single Item Page</a></li>
                              <li><a href="portfolio-single-big.html" class="sf-with-ul">Single Large Item Page</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">
                           Blog
                           <span class="sf-sub-indicator">
                           <i class="fa fa-angle-down "></i>
                           </span>
                           </a>
                           <ul>
                              <li><a href="blog-left-sidebar.html" class="sf-with-ul">Left Sidebar Blog</a></li>
                              <li><a href="blog-right-sidebar.html" class="sf-with-ul">Right Sidebar Blog</a></li>
                              <li><a href="blog-small.html" class="sf-with-ul">Small Blog</a></li>
                              <li><a href="single-post.html" class="sf-with-ul">Single Post</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">
                            Contact
                            <span class="sf-sub-indicator">
                              <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                            </span>
                            </a>
                            <ul>
                              <li><a href="contact.html" class="sf-with-ul">Contact</a></li>
                              <li><a href="contact-2.html" class="sf-with-ul">Contact 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                         </li>
                     </ul>
                  </nav>
                  <!-- Menu End --> 
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Main Header End -->
         </header>
         <!-- Header End --> 
';?>
```

Comment: The html is not a string. <?PHP  ?> can be at the start of your php page, but you need regular html markup in the header.php page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Remove <?php and ?> tags, inside the script only have html code.
```

Your script is only:

```
'long string';
```

A string between quotes inside a php no generate any output, you need remove the php tags or add a "print" function before the string.

Comment: In the script on my topic, or do you mean to fix the problem?

Comment: Never mind, I tried it and it worked, mind enlightening me? I have tried the other way for a different website and it worked.

Comment: <?php 'string'; ?> no return any result.

<?php print 'string'; ?> return "string" result.

string (without php tags) => return "string" result.

No other way sorry.

Comment: I understand now, if It happened to be mixed though would I do what was shown above, vs adding them together? Actually now that I remember I think I was using <?php echo' ';?> before.

Comment: i'm happy to can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Either use eco after your

```
<?PHP  //any php code. ?>

  <!-- Header Start -->
         <header id="header">
            <!-- Header Top Bar Start -->
            <div class="top-bar">
               <div class="slidedown collapse">
                  <div class="container">
                     <div class="phone-email pull-left">
                        <a><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Call Us : +880 111-111-111</a>
                        <a href="support@fifothemes.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Email : support@fifothemes.com</a>
                     </div>
                     <div class="pull-right">
                        <ul class="social pull-left">
                           <li class="facebook"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                           <li class="twitter"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                           <li class="dribbble"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                           <li class="linkedin"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                           <li class="rss"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div id="search-form" class="pull-right">
                           <form action="#" method="get">
                              <input type="text" class="search-text-box" placeholder="Search...">
                           </form>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Header Top Bar End -->
            <!-- Main Header Start -->
            <div class="main-header">
               <div class="container">
                  <!-- TopNav Start -->
                  <div class="topnav navbar-header">
                     <a class="navbar-toggle down-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".slidedown">
                     <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa fa-current"></i>
                     </a> 
                  </div>
                  <!-- TopNav End -->
                  <!-- Logo Start -->
                  <div class="logo pull-left">
                     <h1>
                        <a href="index.html">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="pixma" width="125" height="60">
                        </a>
                     </h1>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Logo End -->
                  <!-- Mobile Menu Start -->
                  <div class="mobile navbar-header">
                     <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href=".navbar-collapse">
                     <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                     </a> 
                  </div>
                  <!-- Mobile Menu End -->
                  <!-- Menu Start -->
                  <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse menu">
                     <ul class="nav navbar-nav sf-menu">
                        <li>
                           <a id="current" href="index.html">
                           Home
                           <span class="sf-sub-indicator">
                           <i class="fa fa-angle-down "></i>
                           </span>
                           </a>
                           <ul>
                              <li><a href="index-2.html" class="sf-with-ul">Home 2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="index-3.html" class="sf-with-ul">Home 3</a></li>
                              <li><a href="index-4.html" class="sf-with-ul">Home 4</a></li>
                              <li><a href="index-nivo.html" class="sf-with-ul">Nivo Slider</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">
                           Features 
                           <span class="sf-sub-indicator">
                           <i class="fa fa-angle-down "></i>
                           </span>
                           </a>
                           <ul>
                              <li><a href="shortcodes.html" class="sf-with-ul">Shortcodes</a></li>
                              <li><a href="icons.html" class="sf-with-ul">Icons</a></li>
                              <li><a href="pricing-table.html" class="sf-with-ul">Pricing Tables</a></li>
                              <li>
                                 <a href="#" class="sf-with-ul"> 
                                 Third Level Menu 
                                 <span class="sf-sub-indicator pull-right">
                                 <i class="fa fa-angle-right "></i>
                                 </span>
                                 </a>
                                 <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">Menu Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">Menu Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">Menu Item</a></li>
                                 </ul>
                              </li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">
                           Pages
                           <span class="sf-sub-indicator">
                           <i class="fa fa-angle-down "></i>
                           </span>
                           </a>
                           <ul>
                              <li><a href="about.html" class="sf-with-ul">About Us</a></li>
                              <li><a href="services.html" class="sf-with-ul">Services</a></li>
                              <li><a href="testimonials.html" class="sf-with-ul">Testimonials</a></li>
                              <li><a href="full-width.html" class="sf-with-ul">Full Width Page</a></li>
                              <li><a href="page-left-sidebar.html" class="sf-with-ul">Left Sidebar</a></li>
                              <li><a href="page-right-sidebar.html" class="sf-with-ul">Right Sidebar</a></li>
                              <li><a href="page-left-navigation.html" class="sf-with-ul">Left Navigation</a></li>
                              <li><a href="page-right-navigation.html" class="sf-with-ul">Right Navigation</a></li>

                              <li><a href="faq.html" class="sf-with-ul">FAQ</a></li>
                              <li><a href="page-404.html" class="sf-with-ul">404 Page</a></li>
                              <li><a href="search-results.html" class="sf-with-ul">Search Results</a></li>
                              <li><a href="sitemap.html" class="sf-with-ul">Sitemap</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">
                           Portfolio
                           <span class="sf-sub-indicator">
                           <i class="fa fa-angle-down "></i>
                           </span>
                           </a>
                           <ul>
                              <li><a href="portfolio-two.html" class="sf-with-ul">2 Column</a></li>
                              <li><a href="portfolio-three.html" class="sf-with-ul">3 Column</a></li>
                              <li><a href="portfolio-four.html" class="sf-with-ul">4 Column</a></li>
                              <li><a href="portfolio-single.html" class="sf-with-ul">Single Item Page</a></li>
                              <li><a href="portfolio-single-big.html" class="sf-with-ul">Single Large Item Page</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#" class="sf-with-ul">
                           Blog
                           <span class="sf-sub-indicator">
                           <i class="fa fa-angle-down "></i>
                           </span>
                           </a>
                           <ul>
                              <li><a href="blog-left-sidebar.html" class="sf-with-ul">Left Sidebar Blog</a></li>
                              <li><a href="blog-right-sidebar.html" class="sf-with-ul">Right Sidebar Blog</a></li>
                              <li><a href="blog-small.html" class="sf-with-ul">Small Blog</a></li>
                              <li><a href="single-post.html" class="sf-with-ul">Single Post</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">
                            Contact
                            <span class="sf-sub-indicator">
                              <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                            </span>
                            </a>
                            <ul>
                              <li><a href="contact.html" class="sf-with-ul">Contact</a></li>
                              <li><a href="contact-2.html" class="sf-with-ul">Contact 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                         </li>
                     </ul>
                  </nav>
                  <!-- Menu End --> 
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Main Header End -->
         </header>
         <!-- Header End -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your header.php file should only open the `<?php` tags when you want to run php. If you're simply adding some html, leave that outside of the `<?php` tags. When you do want to run a php script, open the `<?php` tags then. Like this:

```
<!-- Header Start -->
     <header id="header">
        <!-- Header Top Bar Start -->
        <div class="top-bar">
           <div class="slidedown collapse">
              <div class="container">
                 <div class="phone-email pull-left">
                    <a><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Call Us : +880 111-111-111</a>
                    <a href="support@fifothemes.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Email : support@fifothemes.com</a>
                 </div>
<?php echo 'This is a php script!'; ?>
                 <div class="pull-right">
                    <ul class="social pull-left">
                       <li class="facebook"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                       <li class="twitter"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                       <li class="dribbble"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
                       <li class="linkedin"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                       <li class="rss"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
```